# How can I put an image in the middle of the top on a page?

Tags: css, angular, sass, styles

I wanted to know how to put an image on the middle top of a page. An example:

(You need at least 10 reputation to post images. So i have to post it like this:) [image]

The HTML for the Navbar is:

```
<div class="sidebar, navs">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse m-0 ad-user sidebar-form, p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white" id="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">             
                        <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <div id="profile_view_image"></div>
                                <span class="hidden-xs">DeviceBooker</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 160px">
                                <li><a href="">Home<i class="fa fa-user"></i> </a></li>
                                <li><a href="/create">Book<i class="fa fa-user"></i> </a></li>
                                <li><a href="/calendar">Kalender<i class="fa fa-key"></i> </a></li>
                                <li><a href="/about"> Info <i class="fa fa-key"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <section><router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: try using flex : ```#profile_view_image{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

steps:-
1. set an image container with fixed height and width
2. put the image inside the image container 
3. set margin: 0px auto; for image container
       -----done---

```css
.image-conatiner{
  width:100px;
  height:60px;
  margin:0px auto;
}

.img-responsive{
  width:100%;
  height:100%:
}
```

```html
<div class="image-conatiner">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="google" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```